# Ignore null or empty values when saving a mongoose array schema type

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following schema:

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    email: [{
        type: String,
        trim: true,
     }]
})
```

When saving a new user,

```
const user = new User({
    email: ["example@example.com", ""]
    //or email: ["example@example.com", null]
})

try{
   await user.save()
} catch (e) {
   console.log(e)
}
```

This will save both those values (including empty string and null respectively).

Is there a way to save only the proper email value while discarding the empty or null value.
Instead of this:

```
"email" : [ 
        "example@example.com", 
        ""
    ],
```

store only the proper email:

```
"email" : [ 
        "example@example.com", 
    ],
```

Currently for other schema fields I am using set. For example, in the user schema above

```
url: {
    type: String,
    set: deleteEmpty
}



const deleteEmpty = (v) => {
  if(!v) {
      return undefined
  }

  return v
}
```

This will of course not save the url field at all if the value is empty or null.
Using this method on the email field above however will generate a null value.

Is there a way to store only the proper email value (i.e. "example@example.com" in this case while ignoring the null or empty value.)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

‍ **I think** you can make it something like this code below  with your `userSchema`:

```
userSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
  this.email = this.email.filter(email => email);
  next();
})
```

The code above ☝️ **will igrone** all `empty` or `null` value in an array. You can try it.

Or the **Second Options**, you can add `required` on your `email` field in your `userSchema`. It's well looks like this code below:

```js
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  email: [{
      type: String,
      trim: true,
      required: true // add some required
   }],
});
```

The code above ☝️, **will give you an error** if you passing an empty string on your array.

I hope it's can help you .

Comment: Why not just `this.email = this.email ? this.email : undefined;`

Comment: This is wrong. Using mongoose 4.x, I was able to insert a null value, even with a field marked `required: true`

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following to achieve what you want.

```js
var arr = ['example@example.com', '']; // variable to keep the an array containing values

var i;
for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  if (arr[i] == null || arr[i] == '') {
    arr.slice(i); // remove null or '' value
  }
}

console.log('normalized array: ', arr);
// schema code
const user = new User({
    email: arr
})

try{
   await user.save()
} catch (e) {
   console.log(e)
}
```

Good luck, I hope I answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone has one or more fields that takes array value and wants to check for each field, I recommend using a middleware on the pre save hook.

```
supplierSchema.pre('save', normalizeArray)


const normalizeArrray = function(next) {

    //take the list of object feilds and for each field check if it is array
    Object.keys(this.toObject()).forEach((field) => {

        if(Array.isArray(this[field])) {

            //removes null or empty values
            this[field] = this[field].filter(field => field)
        }
    })

    next()
}
```

This just builds on the answer already approved above.

Answer (score 0):

Simply set the default value of the field you wish to ignore, if empty, to `undefined`. Also, set `required` to `false`.

Use the code below:

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    email: [{
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        required: false,
        default: undefined
     }]
})
```

Comment: TypeError: Invalid value for schema path `default`